# How to create a VPN connection to a FortiGate Firewall in Ubuntu 18.04 Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, fortigate

how do I setup and create a SSL-VPN-tunnel using Ubuntu 18.04 Linux?

I downloaded the Forticlient.

On Windows I see a “REMOTE ACCESS” option on the left side of the client.

[image]

However on Ubuntu 18.04 Linux I do not see the same menu:

[image]

So how do I setup and create a SSL-VPN-tunnel using Ubuntu 18.04 Linux?

Most of the Fortinet knowledge base pages are mostly blank: Tested with Firefox and Chromium.

Also is it possible with standard linux tools to connect or must I use the FortiGate Forticlient to connect?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/696137/open-source-fortigate-forti-ssl-vpn-client-support-in-ubuntu you can use the regular network manager to connect to Forti VPN's

Answer (score 8):

The remote access is currently not available in Forticlient 6.0 for Linux.
You can see the official compatibility chart when you scroll down in the following link:
[Forticlient compatibility](https://www.forticlient.com/techspec)

You can use the openfortivpn client:
[Installing openfortivpn](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn#installing)

FortiClient 6.2, Fabric Agent with Endpoint Protection and Cloud Sandbox, can be purchased and the Linux version supports SSL VPN:
[FortiClient 6.2 Compatibility](https://www.forticlient.com/techspec/6.2)

Edit: FortiClient 7.0 VPN is available for Linux too
[FortiClient VPN-only](https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads#vpn)

Answer (score 4):

Here is [Forticlient – SSLVPN](https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/) app we use at my work as an alternative to FortiClient for linux users.

The interface is very similar to forticlient:
[image]

<sup>much better alternative if you ask me, as it does not silently install antivirus bloatware ;)</sup>

Comment: How does it achieve what is asked? How do you use it? How do you set it up? Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330)

Comment: I installed the app. It is great. But the GUI gets the error <pre>Could not load editor VPN plugin for 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.fortisslvpn' (missing plugin file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-fortisslvpn-editor.so").</per> I connect the VPN server using command line